# How to pass user info to another API?

Tags: identityserver3

We are using IdenityServer 3 with OpenID connect to authenticate users in our UI to API 1.
API 1 also communicates with API 2, but API 2 is not reachable from the UI, so we can't use the same id token.
What is the best way to pass on the authenticated user from API 1 to API 2?

Comment: You might be interested in using the client credentials grant. As it is server-to-server, you would need to supply your own user context information. Your choice behind this also depends on the level of trust between the two machines.

Comment: Do you have an example for that?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/SampleAspNetWebApi) is an API using bearer token authentication. And [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/ConsoleClientCredentialsClient) is a client of that API.